# The following Boolean expression will be evaluated to what value? !(false) && (5 > 4)

Tags: java, conditional-operator

The following Boolean expression will be evaluated to what value?

```
!(false) && (5 > 4)
```

I would have thought it evaluated to false, can someone explain what happens that makes it true?

Comment: `!(false)` is true

Comment: And `(5 > 4)` is also `true`.

Comment: You can run a program to find out. It is unclear why you can not do so.

Answer (score 3):

> I would have thought it evaluated to false, can someone explain what happens that makes it true?

`&&` evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is false, results in `false`; otherwise, it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that result as its result. Starting with

```
!(false) && (5 > 4)
```

`!(false)` is `true`, so that's:

```
true && (5 > 4)
```

Since `true` isn't false, `&&` evaluates the right-hand operand:

```
(5 > 4)
```

`(5 > 4)` is also `true`, so the `&&` result is `true`.

Comment: *(Apologies for the earlier JavaScript answer to this question.)*

Answer (score 1):

- You are using `&&` operator. That means your second condition will be
  considered.
- `!` indicates **Negation**. Negation of `false` gives    `true`.
- `5 > 4` is always `true`.
- so, here `true && true` gives    `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
!(false) && (5 > 4)

!(false) = true //because of !(not) operator

(5 > 4) = true

so 

true && true = true
```